# How to get value of an XML tag of varchar(MAX) string type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am working with SQL Server 2016.

I have a table **employee_xml** which has a column **employee_xml_string** of `varchar(MAX)` type.

```
CREATE TABLE employee_xml 
(
     employee_xml_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
     employee_xml_string VARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

`employee_xml_string` column stores an XML string; for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Employee>
      <EmployeeNumber>58913A</EmployeeNumber>
      <FirstName>Shanee</FirstName>
      <LastName>McKenzie</LastName>
      <GovernmentIdentificationNumber>749146551</GovernmentIdentificationNumber>
   </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I want to write SQL to get the value of `<GovernmentIdentificationNumber>` tag. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: If it stores only XML - why **Isn't** it a column of **type** `XML` ???

Comment: @marc_s this table was created long time ago so I guess at that time XML datatype was either not introduced yet or DB guy was hesitant to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value of your XML to `xml` (so I hope they're all valid XML values) and then you can use XQUERY against that converted value:

```
SELECT V.Employee_XML.value('(Employees/Employee/GovernmentIdentificationNumber/text())[1]','int') AS GovernmentIdentificationNumber
FROM dbo.employee_xml E
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(xml,E.employee_xml_string))) V(Employee_XML);
```

Ideally, however, you should be storing XML data as an `xml`; that's what it's there for after all.

Comment: perfect, I really liked the TRY_CONVERT usage here

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nodes` to shred your xml in lines, then you can select the correct item with `value`:

```
;with x as
(
    select cast(employee_xml_string as xml) as employee_xml
    from employee_xml
)
SELECT
    t.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS GovernmentIdentificationNumber
FROM x
CROSS APPLY x.employee_xml.nodes('//Employees/Employee/GovernmentIdentificationNumber') t(s)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could have stored xml as XML. Having said that, you can always CAST it:

```sql
SELECT employee_xml_xml.value('(/Employees/Employee/GovernmentIdentificationNumber)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM employee_xml
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(employee_xml_string AS xml)) AS x(employee_xml_xml)
```